# Wordpress wp-config.php doesn't update in Dockers?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

I am using Wordpress and docker container. The problem is that I updated the wp-config.php file but everything looks the same. 
I have something like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   NAMES
b2711d4b72a1        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   website_phpmyadmin_1
8a89ee46d673        wordpress:4.7.5         website_wordpress_1
2a167667f705        mysql:5.7               website_db_1
```

My docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
wordpress:
depends_on:
  - db
image: wordpress:4.7.5
restart: always
volumes:
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content 
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
ports:
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
networks:
  - back
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
networks:
  - back
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
       - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
        networks:
      - back
     networks:
       back:
      volumes:
  db_data:
```

I have run docker-compose up, build and down but everything is the same.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The official WordPress docker image will automatically configure wp-config.php using the environment variables you set [[documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/)].

If there are any variables such as `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST`, `WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD`, etc., they will be used to build a `wp-config.php` file upon container creation.

If you want to provide a custom `wp-config.php` file, you need to make sure there are no related environment variables, and create a volume mapping for your modified file, like so:

```
version: '2'
...
volumes:
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content 
  - ./wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php
...
```

On `docker-compose up`, Docker will load your custom wp-config.php into the container and then run the WordPress image's [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) which updates the file with the values set in your environment variables.

Comment: It works for wp-content, not for wp-config.php: `sed: cannot rename ./sedhxG4ZS: Device or resource busy`. It looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032744/unable-to-edit-etc-resolv-conf-in-docker-container

Comment: It works for `wp-config.php`, **if there are no related environment variables set**. If you set any env vars that are used to populate wp-config, then the mapping won't work.

Comment: Confirming it words in August 2023 exactly as highlighted by @that-brazilian-guy, if you set even one environment variable that begins with `WORDPRESS_` it will fail, don't set any and it will use `wp-config.php`. Note, if you are behind a reverse proxy in Docker as I was, copy the reverse proxy resolution from `wp-config-docker.php` to your `wp-config.php` or it will also fail.

Answer (score 18):

You can make use of the `WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA` environment variable to define any other config values in the `wp-config.php` file.

As an example:

```
WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
  define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
  define('MULTISITE', true);
  define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick:

```
wp:
  image: wordpress:latest
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    - ./wp-config.php:/usr/src/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
```

When local wp-config.php changes you should delete /var/www/html/wp-config.php from container, docker will copy it again... but it works!

Comment: Actually, removing the `wp-config.php` file is the solution I was looking for. At startup, it is recreated using the `WORDPRES_...` variables. The docker logs shows : `No 'wp-config.php' found in /var/www/html, but 'WORDPRESS_...' variables supplied; copying '/usr/src/wordpress/wp-config-docker.php' (WORDPRESS_DB_HOST WORDPRESS_DB_NAME WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD WORDPRESS_DB_USER WORDPRESS_DEBUG)`

Comment: I dont know about the time of 2018, but in 2023 it must be wp-config-docker.php that you should override