# chown: /etc/resolv.conf: Read-only file system

Tags: linux, docker

I have this `dockerfile` which errors - I believe it errors during run because there are lack of permissions set on the docker `user`. I am not sure that the user should be declared as `app` after the `RUN` command is executed. But I am not great with docker and the person who wrote this is on holiday.

Also, this `docker` file is executed as part of `docker-compose up`

Any insights?

```
ENV CONFIG_ROOT="/etc/"

USER root

COPY . $HOME/myproject

RUN mkdir /etc/myproject && \ 
    cp -R $HOME/myproject/.envs/myproject $CONFIG_ROOT && \
    chown app:app -R $CONFIG_ROOT && \
    chown app:app -R $HOME

USER app

RUN pip install --user myproject/ && \
                rm -rf $HOME/myproject

ENTRYPOINT ["myproject"]
```

Error

> [3/4] RUN mkdir /etc/myproject &&     cp -R /home/app/myproject/.envs/myproject /etc/ &&     chown app:app -R /etc/ &&     chown app:app -R /home/app:
> #7 0.238 chown: /etc/hosts: Read-only file system
> #7 0.326 chown: /etc/resolv.conf: Read-only file system

> executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdir /etc/myproject &&     cp -R $HOME/myproject/.envs/myproject $CONFIG_ROOT &&     chown app:app -R $CONFIG_ROOT &&     chown app:app -R $HOME]: exit code: 1

Comment: Why are you trying to chown every file in /etc? There are lots of files in there that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: The (build) containers get a few "special" files (`/etc/resolv.conf`) from the host. Exact implementation seems version dependent. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41033030/7868781, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348406/494713. That said, you probably don't want to be `chown`-ing this way anyway.

Comment: @BMitch thankfully it errored then and no hijacking took place! I agree that it seems overkill on many fronts.

@frippe if I remove `chown app:app -R $CONFIG_ROOT` it runs ok.  Thanks for the link, I have a better understanding of the problem as well now.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, you need create your container with **--privileged** parameter.

ex.:

```
docker run --privileged -i --name master --hostname k8s-master -d ubuntu:20.04
```

Comment: Do not do this. This is a very dangerous way to solve the wrong problem. You're giving up the security benefits of containerisation by using `--privileged`.